# Trying to get a random Number for two String lists

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an app that helps kids to learn French but I have difficulties getting a random number twice, so that if the user presses the second button he gets the German answer.

```
package com.example.calebseeling.french;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FrenchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button Next;
    private TextView German;
    private TextView French;
    private Button Answer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_french);

        Answer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Answer);
        German = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.German);
        French = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.French);
        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);


        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String getLetter = Letter.getLetter();
                German.setText(getLetter);
            }
        });
        Answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });


        }


}
```

And here is the following code for the Strings:

```
package com.example.calebseeling.french;

import java.util.Random;

public class Letter {

    public static String[] Letters = {
        "Oui",
        "Ca va"
    };
    public static String[] LettersG = {
        "Ja",
        "Wie Gehts"
    };

    public static String getLetter() {
        Random randomgenerator = new Random();
        int Random = randomgenerator.nextInt(Letters.length);
        return Letters[Random];
    }
}
```

In the first sample, there is the `Answer` listener that is empty. This is where I would like to get the answer from the German array. What can I do ? I would like them to correspond, so at the moment I thought about picking a number and getting the corresponding answer, but I can't figure out how, through the Activity. Can you help me ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does the code currently do, and what do you want it to do? Please show the actual/desired output.

Comment: Please explain your question properly. What do you mean by "second button"?

Comment: You should not expect people to guess what is your problem. But you are using random generator incorrectly. Did you read documentation on what it does and how it should be used? Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if I press the button Next a French word comes and I want that if I use the Button "Answer" that I get the German Answer. But I tried to get the same random Number twice so that as an example: the random number is 1 I want that I get the German Word for the number 1.If my English is bad, then its because I'm german.

Comment: There is no guarantee that you will generate a random number again. Better generate a random number and store it in a variable for later use.

Comment: You might want to consider storing the corresponding fr and de strings together: create a small class, something like `class FrenchGermanPair` (or `QuestionAnswer`, perhaps), with getters for the two strings. It's easier to do that than have to maintain the two arrays separately.

Comment: You're generating a random number, using  it to look up a French phrase, and then **throwing away** the random number.  You need to **store** that random number so that you can use it later to find the corresponding German phrase.   You can't force `Random` to give you the same number again, it gives you a new, possibly different **random number** every time you call `nextInt`.

Comment: How can Is store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't very clear, but here is my attempt -

```
package com.example.calebseeling.french;

import java.util.Random;

public class Letter {

    private static Random randomgenerator = new Random();
    private static int randomNumber;

    public static String[] Letters = {
        "Oui",
        "Ca va"
    };
    public static String[] LettersG = {
        "Ja",
        "Wie Gehts"
    };

    public static String getLetter() {
        randomNumber = randomgenerator.nextInt(Letters.length);
        return Letters[randomNumber];
    }

    public static String getCorrespondingGermanLetter() {
        return LettersG[randomNumber];
    }
}
```

What we are doing here is basically saving the generated random number. 
So if you need the same German word, you can do so by calling `getCorrespondingGermanLetter`.

By the way they are `words` not `letters`.

Answer (score 1):

What about simply returning a number from the method instead of a String:

```
int getRandomNumber(){...}
int a = getRandomNumber();
```

then fetch items from your arrays based on this number